# How do you handle HTML element IDs and Javascript references when adding line items using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dhtml

First off, I read all of the suggested questions that sounded halfway relevant and didn't find anything that addressed my issue.  Second, if this is already addressed somewhere, I didn't search well enough for it.  Finally, on to the problem.  :D

I have a page that has a 'line item' on it.  A 'line item', for our purposes, is simply a bunch of HTML elements in a horizontal row that form a line of HTML inputs (for example, imagine columns such as Pieces, Description, Weight, Unit Rate, Total Rate).  One of the HTML controls in our line item is actually a custom server control that emits some Javascript.  Among other things, the Javascript news up an object of type X like so:

`var whatever = new X(constructor values);`

Now, the user can add line items with an Add button.  Currently, I'm simply cloning a clean copy of the HTML that forms the line item.  This also clones the Javascript code so that now, every line item has the `var whatever = new X(constructor values);`.  This presents a problem in that there are several lines all referencing the same Javascript variable (namely, `whatever`).

This, of course, ruins everything b/c I need to reference each of the `whatever`'s as separate instances, not the same instance.  I'm wondering if there are approaches to handling this situation.  How do I use the custom server control but still reference the Javascript that each row emits?  Or how do I create a new line item in a way that avoids this issue?

I'm new to the whole modify-the-DOM-using-Javascript arena, and I can't seem to find any best practices or examples that are helpful so I'm at a bit of a loss.

Does all this make sense?  If not, please let me know what doesn't and I'll try to clear it up as best I can.

**EDIT:**  Here's a small code sample.

This is exactly what the JavaScript object declaration looks like:

`var example = new SmartDropDown('uomSDD','75','1','7','','','','',2);`

The first parameter is the HTML ID of one of the elements that renders and because of that reason I couldn't *just* use an array (as mentioned in one of the answers; awesome answer, though, until I realized I'd forgotten to mention that detail).  I'd need to come up with a way to change the ID *and* use the array.

Some of the methods on the SmartDropDown object are `ShowOptions`, `HideOptions`, `BindOptions`.

As for the code that's called when the button is clicked, here it is:

```
function AddLineItem()
{
    var lineItemsParent = $("lineItems");
    var newRow = lineItemTemplateNode.cloneNode(true);
    lineItemsParent.appendChild(newRow);
}
```

So, to summarize, the line item HTML contains the usual stuff:  inputs, selects, spans, etc and then the JS declaration listed above.  And because of the way I'm adding a new line item (using the code above), the JS variable gets cloned, too.  And I need a way to 1) change the ID of the element and 2)  keep track of all the JS references (an array has already suggested).

Comment: What is the purpose of JavaScript object x for each line item?

Comment: The control that renders the JS is a homegrown Auto-Complete Drop Down of sorts and the JS object that renders is the object that allows for interaction with it through JS.  Is that enough Info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array?

```
   var lineItems = [];
   ...
   // when the button is clicked
   lineItems[lineItems.length] = new X(constructor values);
```

If you need to generate a new id  at the same time, you can prepend a string to the array index.

```
   var lineItems = [];
   ...
   // when the button is clicked
   var id = 'item_' + lineItems.length.toString()
   lineItems[lineItems.length] = new X(id, ...);
```

Comment: Ahhh, beaten to the punch!  I even had the little ellipsis in my code sample. ;)

Comment: Oh, I see.  Interesting.  Let me toy with this a little bit and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Oh, shoot.  I forgot one of the parameters for the constructor is an HTML ID, so I'd have to generate a new, unique ID for each line item.

Comment: As it turned out, the issue I was trying to solve with this question wasn't the issue at all.  However, if I were trying to do this, I prefer this answer to the others simply because I doesn't require me to learn another framework (though there's nothing wrong with that).  Thanks to all for their input.

Answer (score 1):

This is where JavaScript frameworks are really handy. Many have good constructors that make this type of thing easy. For example, using [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), I can do this:

```
function buildMe(counter) {
    var tempHTML = new Element('div',{'id':'bleh'+counter,className:'product'})
    tempHTML.insert(new Element('a',{className:'prodTitleLinkA',href:'/here'})

    $('someDiv').insert(tempHTML)
    Event.observe('bleh'+count, 'click', function(event) {
       alert(element.id)
    });
}
```

This creates a few elements, and connects an event to them. I can keep shoving as many as I want into "someDiv", each with its own ID and event.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'll need a little bit more info to be able to give you a good answer on this one. Could you show some example code how this function of yours is called, what is assigned to *var whatever* and other information you want/can give away. The more the better!

I'll gladly help if I can.